# str.replace() function of pandas doesn't work when you want to replace 'Ã?' by another string, how to solve the problem?

Tags: pandas, replace

I'm working on data that was recorded in the wrong encoding at the time of insertion into the database. As a result, I end up with data like this for example:

'Je suis trÃ?s content, merci.'

So I used str.replace() to change 'Ã@' by 'é', 'Ã§' by 'ç' in my data column, so far it's working fine.

But when I replace Ã? with 'é', I get this result:

'écéeététéeé éféoénécétéiéoéné énéeé éméaérécéh...
éçéaé énéeé éméaérécéhéeé épéaésé

The function sees the character 'Ã?' between each letter,

One solution is to use the replace() function instead of str.replace() which can be applied to each row of the array with a for loop. However this function is too long when the volume of data becomes large. The str.replace() function, on the other hand, works in a few seconds. I tried to import the data with utf8 and latin1 but nothing changes.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please try to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question to help us help you. Specifically, what code did you try?

Comment: You might prefer replacing with 'è' instead of 'é' to get a correct sentence in french ;)

Comment: Good eye Tikoloche ! French is not an easy language ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is you are using the literal string `'Ã?'` in your replace query, e.g.

```py
s.str.replace('Ã?', 'é')
```

The default behavior for `Series.str.replace` is to interpret the first example as a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). From the [`pandas.Series.str.replace` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

> When pat is a string and regex is True (the default), the given pat is compiled as a regex.

To search for the string literal `'Ã?'`, either include the flag `regex=False` in your call to `str.replace`, or escape the question mark with a backslash: `'Ã\?'`:

```py
>>> s.str.replace('Ã?', 'é', regex=False)
0    Je suis trés content, merci.
dtype: object
```